# Find Where Syntax Error in Flex Yacc Happened

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lex

I am pretty new to lex and yacc.

I'm designing a compiler which can make three-address-code.

How can I found where syntax error happen in my code ?

after entering :

```
flex lexer.l
bison -dy parser.y
gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o program.exe
```

I try this input :

```
{ int abc = 234 ; }
```

and then it gives me syntax error!

How can i Fix it?

This is my Lexer

lexer.l:

```
%{

#include "y.tab.h"
#include <string.h>
int yyerror(char *errormsg);

%}

letter  [a-zA-z]
digit   [0-9]
id      {letter}({letter}|{digit})*
ws      [ \t]


%%
{ws}        ;
\{          { return 300; }
\}          { return 301; }
\;          { return SEMICOLON; }
"if"        { return IF; }
"int"       { return INT; }
"float"     { return FLOAT; }
"char"      { return CHAR; }
\=          { return ASSIGN; }      
{id}        {strcpy(yylval.str,yytext) ; return ID; }
{digit}+    {yylval.ival=atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
.           {yyerror("Invalid Command");}
%%



int main(void)
{
   yyparse();
   printf("DONE");
   return 0;
}

int yywrap(void)
{
   return 0;
}

int yyerror(char *errormsg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "hey!%s\n", errormsg);
    exit(1);
}
```

This is my Parser

parser.y:

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int yylex(void);
int yyerror(const char *s);

%}


%union{int ival; double dval; char str[120]; }

%token INT ASSIGN NUMBER IF SEMICOLON
%token FLOAT
%token ID CHAR

%%

Program: 
        Block
        ;

Block:
        '{' Stmts '}'
        ;

Stmts:
        Stmts Stmt
        | Stmt
        ;

Stmt:
        Block
        |IfStmt
        |AssignStmt
        |DeclStmt
        ;


IfStmt:
        IF '(' Expr ')' Stmt  { printf("if found"); }
        ;


AssignStmt:     
        Type ID ASSIGN Expr SEMICOLON { printf("int found!"); }
        ;

DeclStmt:
        Type ID SEMICOLON
        ;


Type:
        INT
        |FLOAT
        |CHAR
        ;


Expr:
    NUMBER
    ;
```

Comment: what's the syntax error? write that in the post

Comment: The syntax error is "syntax error". That's just what syntax errors look like in Bison using the default options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you want to do when trying to figure out a syntax error with Bison is to add the `%define parse.error verbose` option to your Bison file. This will change the error message to something more helpful than just "syntax error". Note that this is a Bison-specific feature, so you'll need to remove the `-y` flag when calling Bison. Doing this, the error message will change to:

```
syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting '{'
```

So it's telling you that it got an `$undefined` when it expected a `{`. So what's an `$undefined`? It's how Bison displays any token whose name it doesn't know. If the token is an integer in ASCII, it'll be displayed as `'x'` (where instead of `x` it'll be the given ASCII character). If the token has been defined using `%token`, it'll be displayed as the name associated with that `%token` declaration. Only when neither is the case, will you get `$undefined`.

So your lexer returns something that is neither an ASCII character nor a defined token. So let's look at your lexer for anything like that and sure enough:

```
\{          { return 300; }
\}          { return 301; }
```

When your lexer sees a brace, it will return 300 or 301 respectively. These are neither characters nor tokens defined using `%token`, so they mean nothing to Bison.

Since your parser expects to see `'{'` and `'}'`, the above should say `return '{';` and `return '}';` respectively (or `return yytext[0];` in both cases if you prefer). Alternatively you could define `%token LBRACE RBRACE` in your parser, use those instead of `'{'` and `'}'` in the `Block` rule and return those in your lexer. Either way you definitely shouldn't return arbitrary integers in your lexer.

---

You'll also want to return 1 instead of 0 in `yywrap` or get rid of it altogether using the `noyywrap` option. Returning 0 makes the lexer wait for further input after reaching the end of file.

Answer (score 1):

You can get bison to output what it's doing by compiling with `-DYYDEBUG=1'`:

```
gcc -DYYDEBUG=1 lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o program.exe
```

and then running with the `yydebug` global variable set to a truthy value:

```
int main(void)
{

    #ifdef YYDEBUG
    yydebug = 1;
    #endif
   yyparse();
   printf("DONE");
   return 0;
}
```

Doing this for your project, yields

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: Next token is token $undefined ()
hey!syntax error
```

IOW, the very first token returned by the lexer is unrecognized by the parser.

You're returning `300` for `{`, but the parser expects `'{'`, so simply fix the lexer rules:

```
//WRONG
\{          { return 300; }
\}          { return 301; }
```

to

```
//OK
 \{          { return '{'; }
 \}          { return '}'; }
```

Then you get a finished parse, though one that hangs.

The hang is caused by you returning `0` in `yywrap`. Changing it to `1` will remove it.